# How do I enable serial access to a computer (not from a computer)?

Tags: linux, serial-port, serial, headless, minicom

I have a Linux server (on Desktop hw) running Ubuntu Server (headless). Its tucked away and hard to access, once a year an update or something else create a problem where I can no longer ssh into it. So my solution has been to take an hour and attach a monitor and a keyboard to it to debug.

Much simpler solution would be to be able to serial into it from something like raspberry pi. Currently there is no serial port in this server, there is an empty PCI-E slot, but I do not think adding a Serial card would do what I want to do. I dont want to access serial connections from this server, I want to access this server via serial.

I know how to do the Rpi part. How do I create an interface (and by what means do I do it?) to be able to serial into this Linux headless server?

Better yet, maybe there is another solution other than serial here? USB to USB? Header on Rpi to USB on server? It cant involve network though, has to be accessible without an ip.

My end goal is to be able to access a server via console from raspberry pi

EDIT: Here is the motherboard, looks like it has a serial header in top left of the board.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not think adding a Serial card would do what I want to do. I dont want to access serial connections from this server, I want to access this server via serial.

That's *literally the same thing.* The hardware is the same, it's just a matter of which side runs the software to show a login prompt.

Serial ports are bidirectional, it's much like how you use the same type of Ethernet card to send packets *and* to receive packets – they're all bidirectional, you don't need to use one type of Ethernet to initiate connections and another type to receive them.

(Well, true, there are slight differences between "DTE" and "DCE" ends of a serial line, but many direct connections just completely ignore all of the additional carrier-detect wires anyway because in the end it doesn't matter – e.g. your Pi probably doesn't even have anything besides Rx and Tx anyway. So that stuff aside, *either* side can print out "Login:" over the serial line, and either side can print out a shell prompt.)

Note though that many slightly older desktops used to actually have a built-in serial port header (4-pin) on the motherboard, even if they lacked the actual DE9 connector.

USB-to-RS232 converters are also an option;  the USB device will be recognized as a serial port. As before, the exact same kind of adapter that people use to connect from a PC to a Pi will work *identically* in the opposite direction as well. (Chaining two such converters to make a "USB-to-RS232-to-USB" cable is possible as well, and would work the same way as a built-in serial port.)

**Note:** The Pi needs something to deal with lower voltages than normal RS232 though – its UART pins use 3.3V signalling, whereas standard ports often work at 5V (or even up to 12-15V). Without some additional electronics the computer's Tx signal has the potential to fry the Pi's UART, while the Pi's Tx signal may be too low to be picked up by the computer.

> How do I create an interface (and by what means do I do it?) to be able to serial into this Linux headless server?

Serial ports are not network interfaces; they are tty lines. As long as the port is recognized by the system, it will automatically have a `/dev/tty*` device node. (The exact naming varies; built-in PC serial ports use `ttyS#` names, while the Pi platform has `ttyAMA#`, and USB-to-RS232 adapters may be either `ttyUSB#` or `ttyACM#`.)

The serial port is always "up" and can transfer data, the only configuration you need to do is set its rate on both sides. Programs such as Minicom or picocom do it automatically; if you want to poke around via shell, use `stty` (note that this is *not* a persistent change):

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyS0 38400

# echo Hello > /dev/ttyS0

# cat /dev/ttyS0
Hello from the other side!
^C
#
```

At this point, you *could* manually start a shell with its input/output attached to the serial line, although this is completely unreliable as far as crashes go:

```
# TERM=vt220 bash </dev/ttyS0 &>/dev/ttyS0
[appears to hang, because its prompt went to ttyS0 instead]
```

To **properly** start a login prompt on a serial tty line, use `getty` – the same as the process that shows login prompts on the local "console" ttys. On systemd-based distributions you can do this by starting the `serial-getty@` service:

```
systemctl enable --now serial-getty@ttyACM0.service
```

The default for agetty in this configuration is to autodetect the speed (baud rate) of the serial line; it can also be set explicitly by editing the service's ExecStart. See plenty of existing tutorials for more information, e.g. Arch Linux Wiki.

For sysvinit-based systems, the equivalent would be adding a "getty" instance to /etc/inittab.

You will likely also want to redirect the *kernel* console (where dmesg warnings and errors are copied) using the `console=` boot option.

```
console=ttyS1,115200n8 console=tty0
```

Finally, redirect your *bootloader* to the serial port – GRUB2 supports displaying its boot menu via serial; this is very useful when you need to somehow boot into an alternate kernel:

```
(/etc/default/grub)
GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --unit=0 --speed=115200"
```

A proper "server" motherboard would also support redirecting its initial boot screens over serial as well. (Then again, a proper "server" motherboard would also support IPMI serial-over-IP.)

---

Alternatively to all of the above, you can in fact run PPP *over* a tty line using `pppd` and create an actual network interface for IP-over-serial (this is how dial-up Internet access worked), but it is not necessary for logging in to the system; it's much simpler to just send the login prompt directly over the same tty line.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thank you. Is there a way to bypass RS232 dapters and go USB to USB? Or RT/TX pinout on Rpi to USB on the server? I typically access serial consoles via minicom -R /dev/ttyS0 -b <baud rate here>. Is this something I can do here?

Comment: "*USB-to-RS232 adapters may be either ttyUSB# or ttyACM#*" -- Not quite accurate. USB-to-RS232 and USB-to-TTL serial adapters will use /dev/ttyUSB# device nodes. A direct USB (host to gadget)) connection using CDC ACM protocol will have /dev/ttyACM# device node.

Comment: Right, but thats least of my worries, I can figure out tty interface to connect to. The hurdle is the wiring. I added picture of the mobo to the original post, looks like there is indeed a header. But ideally I do some sort of USB to USB connection that would be perfect. I am not sure how to do that though.

Comment: @Duxa: The "Rx/Tx" pins on the RPi are not USB, so I'm not sure why you imagine you can connect them to a USB port without any kind of adapter. (That's literally the reason RS232-to-USB adapters exist!) Direct "USB-to-USB" _may_ be possible, but only if you enable the "USB device/gadget" mode in your Pi and set up `g_serial` on it... or if you find one of those active A-to-A cables with a double RS232 converter sneakily hidden in the middle. (I know those exist for Ethernet via USB.) But you can't just show a login prompt over raw USB, generally.

Comment: @Duxa: So if you have a built-in serial port on the PC side, that's going to be either ttyS0 or ttyS1 (i.e. COM1 or COM2 respectively), and the serial port on the RPi side is ttyAMA0, I believe? Basically, follow the _exact_ same procedure as connecting from a PC to Pi, to make sure the wiring is correct, perhaps test with minicom on both ends, and once you're done just start serial-getty on the PC.

Comment: @Duxa: Upon closer look, I am not seeing any serial-port header on your PC motherboard, so you probably will need to add one externally (either USB or PCIe).

Comment: @user1686 I dont have to use the USB ports on Rpi, I can use the pinout header if needed. Look in the top left of the motherboard near audio jack, white background black lettering says "Serial".  Looks like its the top edge of that pinout, the bottom is for Keyboard/Mouse (unless KB and MS stand for something else).

Comment: @Duxa: Ah, yes, I missed that – usually I see it as a standalone header, not intermixed with other stuff. (KB/MS probably refers to the old PS/2 ports; I guess a combined header makes sense for that since both go to the same chip nowadays.) You _could_ connect that "directly" to the Pi's UART pins, through a voltage converter.

Comment: Do I need to involve power? I cant just use UART_TXD0 and UART_RXD0 pins on Rpi? and then figure out which of those pins on the motherboard are RX/TX pins?

Comment: Power is literally how signals are transmitted, so yes. Even if it's not power _supply,_ it's still electric signals in certain voltages – and the UART on the Pi is apparently built for 3.3V signalling whereas standard serial ports might use 5V or even up to 12V, so there is potential for the PC to fry the Pi's serial interface if you just directly connect the two. Or it might be perfectly fine, but at least measure what the PC outputs first. (There appear to be [two "standards"](https://pinoutguide.com/Motherboard/rs232_header_pinout.shtml) for the serial header on the PC.)

Comment: i can definitely do a voltage measurement, and then I guess use a resistor (need to bring out ohms law) to bring it down to ~3.5v. So then for software side of things, on Rpi I can connect to appropriate tty device. But on the server, do I need to pipe the standard out to serial or anything like that? Or it should just magically work?

Comment: What "standard out" are you talking about? I mean, yes, you can just read/write to /dev/ttyS0, but I'm not sure whether by "just magically work" you mean just the serial data transfer in general, or whether you mean getting a shell and/or a login prompt specifically. (It's indeed possible to just manually start a shell with its stdin/stdout/stderr redirected from/to the tty device, but usually that's best left to getty – for a full-featured login prompt on ttyS0, see the part regarding getty in my main post.)

Comment: If you do not use 'agetty', then you'll want to set the rate manually using `stty` first, making sure it's identical on both sides; 1) echo something to the tty device on one end, and see if cat/picocom/Minicom receives it on the other end; 3) try typing between two minicom/picocom instances; 4) try manually running `TERM=vt220 bash </dev/ttyS0 &>/dev/ttyS0` as an experiment, and see if you get a shell prompt on the other end; 5) finally start getty on the serial line for proper login handling.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use an RPi - there's kits that essentially give you *full* remote access with version 3 onwards - including remote keyboard and display over network, with the raspberry pi acting almost like a server grade IPMI/iDrac device - devices like the [Pi KVM](https://pikvm.org)(or its clones) or [tinypilot](https://tinypilotkvm.com) essentially put your (newer) Pi in gadget mode to act as a keyboard, use a video capture card to capture screen output, and use some software to give you a nice interface for all that. There's even provision for power switch control on an ATX type system on some devices

Answer (score 0):

If the update is borked, then connecting via the serial line may still not work.

What you need is to connect via ILO, bmc or ipmi. These are all out of band and allow you to take control of the system even if the o/s has crashed.

You can get these as add-in cards, but your milage may vary as to how well they work.